# Alt-TAB and Windows key not working on a new laptop

Tags: laptop

I just bought a new laptop (Lenovo T410s), and I notice that the Windows key and ALT-TAB don't function. I imagine some kind of function-lock or setting is causing this, but I haven't been able to figure out how to disable it. How do I regain usage of ALT-TAB and Windows key?

Comment: The *ThinkPad* T410s is an excellent machine - a very good choice (the slim 's' version is almost like an X-series ultracompact).

Comment: Yeah, my workplace just bought it for me. Main reason I upgraded my desktop to it is the 160GB SSD :)

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently a known issue on that model Lenovo.

[This thread details it somewhat.](http://forum.notebookreview.com/lenovo-ibm/510718-t410s-w-switchable-graphics-first-impressions-compared-x301-2.html)

It sounds like a BIOS setting, but I can't find directions on resetting it.  Does it show up in your documentation?

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Start
- Type `Effects`
- Click Find and fix the problems transparency
- Click Next
- When it's finished, close it
- Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

- Try installing MS Power Tool for Alt-Tab
- Try installing this 3rd party software [Alt-Tab Thingy](http://www.nymtec.com/alt-tab-thingy)
- Go to Start => Run and type in regedit

  Navigate to:
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop

  Look in the right-hand pane for the String 'CoolSwitch'
  If it has a Value of 0, right-click on 'CoolSwitch' , click 'Modify' and change the Value to 1

  OK and exit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how, but the problem seems to have resolved itself somehow.

Comment: It is not acceptable answer.